# image from below

Tags: android

I'd like to make an animation that shows a tab sliding from below the screen, by clicking on a button. 
Now I have a code that shows an image sliding from right to left:

```
Im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Im_Tab);
SlidingImage = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,-560);
SlidingImage.addUpdateListener((animatedValue)->{
                findViewById(R.id.arrow_long);
                float distanceTraveled = (float)animatedValue.getAnimatedValue();
                Im.setTranslationX(distanceTraveled);
            });
```

And this is the animation start:

```
mButtonTranslator.start();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: how about writing a simple view based animation in xml and accessing it using Animation utils! its much simpler and easy to work out with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to switch axis, you can simply replace Im.setTranslation**X**(distanceTraveled); with Im.setTranslation**Y**(distanceTraveled);